# What is the difference between the adjective "health-conscious" and "health-minded"?

Tags: difference, adjectives

What is the difference between the adjective *health-conscious* and *health-minded*? For example:

> Kate doesn't drink or smoke. Se is **health-concious**, which is a real asset.
>
> Kate doesn't drink or smoke. She is **health-minded**, which is a real asset.

Comment: There is no significant difference (and Kate is a female name!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are very similar and in most cases can be switched out without a significant difference in meaning. If you are looking to subtleties, "health-conscious" is [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1800&content=health%20minded%2C%20health%20conscious&smoothing=3&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chealth%20minded%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chealth%20conscious%3B%2Cc0), and from "consciousness" has a slight connotation of ongoing awareness, a whole state of being or habits; whereas "health-minded" has a slight connotation or emphasis from "mind" of being about something more deliberate or intentional, "a health-minded decision to stop smoking".